# This configuration section cannot be used at this path

Tags: python, django, windows-10, iis-8

I know this has been asked before and i have tried quite a few options but to no result. I just added my Django website to IIS and I'm in the process or trying to set the handler mappings.

However when I click on Handler Mappings for my site I get this error:
[image]

this is the line in my web.config that craps out:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="Python FastCGI" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="%INTERPRETERPATH%|%WFASTCGIPATH%" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

I just cannot get this to work. Is there a configuration I may have forgotten to unlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to install `ASP.NET 4.5` using the web platform installer